# Dataset Attribute in 'h5py' file

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train my CNN model but I run into the error:
AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'Dataset'

```
train = train_data[:-500]    
test = train_data[-500:] 

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit(X ,Y , n_epoch=3, validation_set=(test_x, test_y),
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

When I run the model.fit below is the error that I receive

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\Anaconda3\envs\Dogs_vs_Cats\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\Anaconda3\envs\Dogs_vs_Cats\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\Anaconda3\envs\Dogs_vs_Cats\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\Anaconda3\envs\Dogs_vs_Cats\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\nikhi\Anaconda3\envs\Dogs_vs_Cats\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 184, in slice_array
    if type(X) == h5py.Dataset:
AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'Dataset'
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are loading the data using h5py? It is not clear from the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Below given is the link where I have pasted my code on Github Gist for reference:
https://gist.github.com/nikhilraphi07/b2492c4285e08bdfeaba1285465efcbf

The train and test files I am loading from my local directory

Comment: Which line is throwing this error? Maybe its because the labels are not being fed as an array but as a list. I am not very familiar with tflearn input structure.

Comment: model.fit(X ,Y , n_epoch=3, validation_set=(test_x, test_y),
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

This is when I get the error while running fit